# multiple variables and complex expressions in AS3 switch case statements

Tags: actionscript-3, switch-statement

I'm cleaning up some AS3 code today, and want to replace a bunch of messy if/else if/else statements with a switch statement.

```
private const myConstant:int = 3;
private var someNumber:int = 1000;
for(var i:int=0; i < someNumber; i++){
    switch(i, myConstant){
        case 0:
            function1();
            break;
        case (i % myConstant == 0):
            function2();
            break;
        default:
            function3();
    }
}
```

My program has many more case statements and variables, however, I cut it down for the sake of brevity. In this example, I want to call `function2()` on every third iteration of the loop. Now, `myConstant` is an important setting for the class which is used elsewhere, so I can't just put a literal `3` in the expression.

1. Can I evaluate multiple variables (and constants) in one switch?
2. Can I evaluate expressions such as the second case statement in my example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switch` keyword takes only one expression inside the parentheses (your comma separated variables above would not evaluate to one expression).

The `case` keyword also expects to evaluate one expression.

In your example, it's unnecessary to pass either `i` or `myConstant` into the switch statement. These vars are declared immediately above the `switch` and are accessible to any code inside the `switch` statement.

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
for (var i:int = 0, i < someNumber; i++)
{
    switch (true)
    {
        case i == 0:
            function1();
            break;
        case i % myConstant == 0:
            function2();
            break;
        default:
            function3();
    }
}
```